# Dropdown control not scrolling on touch device (specifically with an app)

Tags: android, html, css, touchscreen

My issue is with drop down on touch device and with app.
I have a drop down of countries whose data is loading with php. When I open this page on mobile device browser it scrolls well with touch screen.

But my page is embedded with an android app, and when I open this page in app the Drop down doesn't scrolls down. It just shows 1st visible 5-6 countries elements when tapped on control, rest is not scrollable.

I am a beginner in HTML CSS designing, can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: no suggestion friends ?????

Comment: If it works in a regular browser, the problem lies within the application.